# C# Threading with Sockets

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

This is another issue with sockets.

I'm making bots for a game in C#, so far I can get them to connect and everything like that, but its just connecting multiple accounts at once on the same socket. I figured I could do that by threading the function that includes the socket.connect() function and then sends packets to the servers. I even looked through a past python script and it was basically doing the same thing.

Here is an example of the Python code:

```
if bots["loaded"] < b0ts:

                    bots["accounts"][acc[0]] = acc[1].replace("\n", "")

                    bot_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.verify_bot, args=(acc[0],))

                    bot_thread.start()
```

Basically I was going to attempt to convert that into C#, figuring it would work. But then on the other hand, pretty much all functions can be different in pretty much every programming language.

Here is the code I have in C# for the threading part, I was using a background worker for some reason, but I also didn't think it would be the reason of it not working so why not.

```
Thread t;                                                             
    private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <= acc.Items.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if(backgroundWorker2.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                t = new Thread(() => verify_bots(acc.Items[i].ToString().Split(':')[0], acc.Items[i].ToString().Split(':')[1]));
                t.Start();
            }
        }
    }
```

The splits are for the usernames and passwords incidentally, just in case anyone had gotten confused with it. Anyway, with all that only 1 bot still connects, then I get an error from the socket either because it was already connected before by one connection or something like that I think or something else.

That is where my problem is, because it works fine in python, and usually things I attempt to convert into C# works. Here is the verify_bots function so that it might be easier for someone to figure it out.

```
private void verify_bots(string username, string password)
    {
        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

        string login_data = string.Format("userID={0}&password={1}", username, password);
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(login_data);

        HttpWebRequest request;

        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.binweevils.com/login");

        getTick(request); // getting cookies

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.UserAgent = "1337JjsHd";
        request.CookieContainer = logincookie;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        Stream stream;

        stream = request.GetRequestStream();
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        stream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response;

        response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        StreamReader responsereader;

        responsereader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        string final = responsereader.ReadToEnd();

        if(final.Contains("register.php"))
        {
            console.Text = console.Text + username+" Failed!\n";
        }
        else
        {
            string post = "";
            ASCIIEncoding encoding1 = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] data1 = encoding1.GetBytes(post);

            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://lb.binweevils.com/php2/weevil/get-login-details.php");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.UserAgent = "1337JjsHd";
            request.CookieContainer = logincookie;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = data1.Length;

            stream = request.GetRequestStream();
            stream.Write(data1, 0, data1.Length);
            stream.Close();

            response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

            responsereader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

            final = responsereader.ReadToEnd();

            try
            {
                string[] a = new string[] { "loginKey=" };
                var aa = final.Split(a, StringSplitOptions.None);
                logkey = aa[1].ToString();
                gethash(@"C:\Python27\hash.py", logkey);
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                console.Text = console.Text + "Failed to get loginkey.\n";
            }

            sock.Connect(ip, port);

            byte[] recv = new byte[2048];

            sendRawPackets(sock, "<policy-file-request/>");
            sock.Receive(recv);
            sendRawPackets(sock, "<msg t='sys'><body action='verChk' r='0'><ver v='154' /></body></msg>");
            sock.Receive(recv);
            if(ip.Contains("sfs1"))
            {
                sendRawPackets(sock, "<msg t='sys'><body action='login' r='0'><login z='Grime'><nick><![CDATA[" + username + "]]></nick><pword><![CDATA["+logkey+"]]></pword></login></body></msg>");
            }
            else
            {
                sendRawPackets(sock, "<msg t='sys'><body action='login' r='0'><login z='Slime'><nick><![CDATA[" + username + "]]></nick><pword><![CDATA[" + logkey + "]]></pword></login></body></msg>");
            }
            sock.Receive(recv);

            sendRawPackets(sock, "%xt%login%1#2%-2");
            sock.Receive(recv);
            sendRawPackets(sock, "%xt%login%2#6%-1%");
            sock.Receive(recv);
            sendRawPackets(sock, "%xt%login%2#7%17610%69%0,-255,190%");
            sock.Receive(recv);
            sendRawPackets(sock, "%xt%login%2#4%3150%FlumsFountain%52.9941101744771%0%989.1726320236921%-180%0%190%");
            sock.Receive(recv);

            string[] move = { "%xt%login%2#1%23%-62%892%66%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%-28%1102%146%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%133%924%-48%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%-39%882%57%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%-39%882%57%", "%xt%login%12#2%23%", "%xt%login%12#2%23%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%54%1002%137%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%-28%934%84%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%144%994%-126%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%84%1118%-177%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%-85%1032%110%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%-34%941%70%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%20%876%17%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%76%951%-79%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%92%999%-133%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%-52%1108%142%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%-92%1045%116%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%19%893%13%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%-84%914%64%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%-19%859%23%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%136%1061%-139%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%91%966%-117%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%63%1086%-156%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%120%1060%-139%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%110%938%-107%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%-84%872%69%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%-117%1045%141%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%-36%961%151%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%72%920%-97%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%117%894%-82%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%32%865%-29%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%-45%889%80%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%-122%1068%141%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%15%1093%-178%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%72%1098%-161%", "%xt%login%2#1%23%83%994%-135%" };

            while(true)
            {
                sendRawPackets(sock, move[new Random().Next(0, move.Length)]); // making bot move around in area
                sock.Receive(recv);
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you ever close the socket? How do you expect the same socket to be shared amongst all these threads you create. And BTW, go read up on `using` statements, `HttpClient` and StackOverflow guidelines on posting a minimal chunk of code illustrating the problem. None of the web request code seems relevant to your question.

Comment: Okay I'll do that, but also to answer ur top question, I said I was looking through a past python script and basically was doing what was in it. The webrequest crap was to be used to verify that the accounts passwords are correct and then hash the key that was given, and then send packets to the games servers to actually connect them to the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already figured everything out. Seems like every time i am stuck on something with a project, i just end up figuring it out myself sooner or later :))))

Thanks anyways.

Comment: Would be beneficial if you could share where you discovered the problem was and what was your approach to solve it.

Comment: basically i put in 

"IPAddress remote = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
            IPEndPoint re = new IPEndPoint(remote, port);"

then i did a using() function with the socket and had the socket connect using the IPEndPoint and then had it do the rest that it needed to do

Answer (score 0):

It takes considerable time for a thread to spin up so by the time one does your `for` loop is finished and `i == acc.Items.Count - 1`. Which means that every thread is using `acc.Items[acc.Items.Count - 1]` and thus "connecting multiple accounts at once on the same socket".

The simple fix is this:

```
    for(int i = 0; i <= acc.Items.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if(backgroundWorker2.CancellationPending == true)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            int a_copy_of_i = i;
            t = new Thread(() => verify_bots(acc.Items[a_copy_of_i].ToString().Split(':')[0], acc.Items[a_copy_of_i].ToString().Split(':')[1]));
            t.Start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: sadly, that did not solve anything with the socket, i still get this error from the socket every time, http://prntscr.com/jea643/direct <-- screenshot

Comment: @HD. - That sounds like a completely different error than the one you're asking about in your question?

Comment: I said that it was either giving errors about too many connections, or something else. I used ur code and I didn't get any extra connection errors or whatever, but now going back to the extra errors thing, don't understand.

Comment: @HD. - So my answer did solve something, but now you're get these other errors?

Comment: it somewhat did at first but then it just started giving me the same thing again, along with that other error.